# jquery mobile page with more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am setting up a j query mobile page showing over 50 elements, any suggestion on how to   show only the first 10 when open up the page, and with a more button on the bottom which can show all if click on it. my script is:

```
<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back" >
<div data-role="header" >
<h1 style="white-space:normal">body</h1>

</div>
<ul  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
<li><a href="http://www.mydomain.co.nz/users/262/">Feature listings</a>   </li>

<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false">

<table>

<li>
    <a href="/users/264/properties/50473">
        <img src="/media/2012/11/01/011528_47689.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=80x60&s=f9e49fbb929e8d1b" />          
        <h3>7C/192 Willis Street</font></font></font>, Beijing</h3>
    <p>Buyer Enquiry Over $305,000<br />Ref: 47689</p></a>
</li>  

<li>
    <a href="/users/264/properties/50474">
        <img src="/media/2012/11/01/011533_47722.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=80x60&s=b4482c7638c512b4" />          
        <h3>606/35 Abel Smith Street</font></font></font>, Te Aro</h3>
        <p>Tender<br />Ref: 47722</p></a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="/users/264/listings/50476">
        <img src="/media/2012/11/01/011539_47691.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=80x60&s=66def46f1524e177" />
        <h3>8/34 William Street</font></font></font>, Hataitai</h3>
        <p>Buyer Enquiry Over $280,000<br />Ref: 47691</p></a>
</li>  ........
....... over 50 elements
```

Comment: So.. you've tried nothing and expect free code.

Comment: I don't know where should I start, thats why I ask here.

Comment: @Daedalus I get your point and partially agree.  It's frustrating when people don't even try, but at the same time I have compassion for newcomers that see too much info out on the web and don't know where to begin.  I'm stuck in the middle on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using slice with your `li` elements and hide those.

First, **hide all** of them with CSS:

```
li { display: none; }
```

Then show the **first 10** in JavaScript, and set up **click event listener** to show the **hidden** ones:

```
$('li').slice(0,10).css('display', 'block');
$('#more-button').click(function() {
    $('li:hidden').show();
});
```

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle I just did showing how to incrementally show 5 more: http://jsfiddle.net/kysGX/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, its really helpful! also thanks for your compassion for newcomers like me!

Comment: @mmmshuddup sorry to border you again, just wonder can I put the CSS and javascript in the head part of the script? I tried it but doesn't work. any idea why?

Comment: @LiNingXuan :) you're welcome!  I'm not sure why it's not working.. Can you paste the entire script (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript) in a pastie?  (http://pastie.org)  I'll take a look.

Comment: @mmmshuddup Please check out: http://pastie.org/5170232 and what it show online is: http://xuanyinwen.com/mobile/examples/remax.htm all elements been hide. many thanks

Comment: @LiNingXuan First, you have some erroneous `</font>` tags in the Martin Square listing, so **delete those**.  Second, I saw that you have your `ul` inside a `table`..  You should **delete** both the `<table>` and `</table>` tags.  Also, I saw you put the CSS in there, but _not_ the **JavaScript**.  Copy and paste the JavaScript example I gave you and try again.  Cheers!

Comment: @mmmshuddup, many thanks for your indicator. I did edit what you said. but it still show the same. my update code: http://pastie.org/5186884 my online webpage show: http://xuanyinwen.com/mobile/examples/remax.htm

Comment: @LiNingXuan I suggest you use Firefox and install Firebug to see what errors you're getting.  I am really not sure.

Comment: Ok, I will try my best to work it out. Thanks again for  your help! May I ask you again if I stuck again. will Stackoverflow notice you if I put the @mmmshuddup in front of my message? cheers